# Randomizing capitalization with regex

Tags: regex

Assume I have any random string, e. g. `I want this randomized!`.

I need a regex to make it look like `i WaNT thIs RaNdOMizEd!` or `I WAnt ThiS RAndomIzED!` etc.

Regex seems like the best choice, seeing as the only other functions I can use are `lowerCase` and `upperCase`...

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: @MichaelD Not much, really, I've experimented with some functions this app has to offer. Didn't really make sense and didn't work, either. I've never really used regex, just a few times. I think I asked questions about it before. - EDIT: I have not, but again, not much experience with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for regex here.

```
import random

your_string = input()
final = ""

for char in your_string:
    if round(random.random()):
        final += char.upper()
    else:
        final += char.lower()

print(final)
```

Explanation:

- Get input from the user.
- Iterate over each `char` in the string.
- Get a random float between zero and one, and round it.
- If this number is `1` (truthy), add the uppercase version  of `char` to the final string.
- Otherwise, add the lowercase version of `char` to the final string.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY0xDsMgDEV3TuFmAlXK0q1S9t6iQg0UJGIjx6jK6SmBpUu9WNZ7/j8fEghvtcYtEwuwxZU2BW3UQYWfu3DENywQMRfRRvmINrV7moblieEVLDcBfj7unUYPTAVXPXLnsbQxA58z8q5LD5lLzo5by0lc2t0/L9Gneyq3MtEdmlofLiUCCY7d5Qs) You can see that it is functioning properly.

Answer (score 0):

I think regex is not the right solution.  Try

```
import random

s='Hello World!'
new_string = ''.join([x.lower() if random.random()>0.5 else x.upper() for x in s])
new_string

>>> 'HElLo wORlD!'
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see an obvious answer with regex. But here is a function written in python 3 that you could try:

```
import random

def uppper_or_lower_char(char):
  if round(random.random()):
    return char.upper()
  else:
    return char.lower()


def randomizing(string):
  randomized_list = map(lambda char: uppper_or_lower_char(char), string)

  return ''.join(randomized_list)

s = 'I want this randomized!'

print(randomizing(s))

# resutl = i want THIS rAndomIzed!
```

Comment: Hello, this seems very similar to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Using Java, here is a rather straight forward approach

```java
   public static String randomize(String s) {
      Random r = new Random();
      char[] chars = s.toCharArray();
      for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
         char c = chars[i];
         chars[i] = r.nextInt(2) == 0 ? Character.toUpperCase(c)
               : Character.toLowerCase(c);
      }
      return new String(chars);
   }
```

- The random number is between 0 and 1 and that is used to determine if the character should be uppercase.
- The builtin Character methods are used for the conversions.

Comment: OP asked for a Python solution.

Comment: Not in the question nor comments.  Otherwise I would not have answered.